# Document API routes using ExDoc

Tags: elixir, documentation, phoenix-framework, ex-doc

I'm new to Elixir and I am wondering if is it possible to document API routes using ExDoc? The Router is included in the documentation but not the routes (as they are not functions).

For example, here is a sample code:

```
scope "/api", MyApp.Api, as: :api do
  pipe_through :api

  scope "/v1", V1, as: :v1 do
    post "/test", MyController, :test
  end
end
```

Can I document this is [ExDoc](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ex_doc), and if yes, how?

Sorry if I missed something obvious!

Comment: Are all those routes not listed on the doc page `MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers.html`?

Comment: @zwippie Only the paths are documented, not the API routes.

Answer (score 1):

> not the routes (as they are not functions)

That is not fully true, but let's ignore that for a moment.

---

Depends on what you mean by the "documenting" routes. If all you want is to list all routes then you can use [`Phoenix.Router.routes/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.6.2/Phoenix.Router.html#routes/1):

```
Phoenix.Router.routes(MyAppWeb.Router)
```

Technically you can even use it inside `@moduledoc` attribute, but with one small gist - you cannot use it within `MyAppWeb.Router` because that module is still not fully compiled when the `@moduledoc` is evaluated. Fortunately you can do all magic in another module. Then in that module you can do:

````
@moduledoc """
Available routes:

```
#{
  for %{verb: verb, path: path} <- Phoenix.Router.routes(MyAppWeb.Router) do
    [String.upcase(to_string(verb)), " ", path, "\n"]
  end
}
```
"""
````

Which will result with something like:

> Available routes:
>
> ```
> POST /test
> ```

In your case.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I tried it but placing the code you provided results in an error `MyAppWeb.Router.__routes__/0 is undefined`.  The same code in a function works great, but cannot be called in the @moduledoc (same error).

Comment: @Jeremie in which module you call that function?